# How To Update Current DOM In For Each Loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm having trouble updating the DOM in a for each loop.

In the code below, $(this).val(updated_value).slider('refresh'); isn't working.

I'm trying to cycle through all slider values in class entry_percent and update the display value (excluding the current selected slider).  Only the current selected is updating.

Here's the loop in question (commented out is some of what I've tried):

```
var sliders = $('.entry_percent').not(this);
        //iterate through each input and add to sum
        $(sliders).each(function() {
            var current_value = parseFloat(this.value);
            console.log('Current slider value: ' + current_value);

            var updated_value = (current_value / slider_sum) * remaining_percent;
            console.log('Updated slider value: ' + updated_value);

           //$(this).slider('value', updated_value);

            //$(this).slider('refresh');

            $(this).val(updated_value).slider('refresh');

        });
```

Here's the full code...

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page"> 

  <!-- entry points table -->
  <section id="entry_points_section">
    <div class="input_fields_wrap">
      <table class="responsive" id="input_entries_table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" id="entry_price_column">Entry price</th>
            <th scope="col">Percent</th>
            <th scope="col">Order amount</th>
            <th scope="col">Capital value</th>
            <th scope="col">Breakeven</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td  width="17%" style="min-width:3em" ><input type="number" class = "entryprice_class" id="entryprice_1" size="5" min="0" placeholder="0" value="0"></td>
            <td style="min-width:2em"><input type="range" name="slider-fill_1" class= "entry_percent" id="entry_percent_1" value="50" placeholder="50%" min="0" max="100"
                               data-highlight="true"/></td>
            <td width="17%" style="min-width:3em"><input type="text" class="order_amount" name="order_amount_name" size="5" min="0" placeholder="0" length="10px" disabled></td>
            <td width="17%" style="min-width:3em"><input type="text" class ="capital_value" name="capital_value" size="5" min="0" placeholder="0"  disabled></td>
            <td width="17%" style="min-width:3em"><input type="text" class ="breakeven" name="breakeven" size="5" min="0" placeholder="0" disabled></td>
            <td width="28px" style="display:none" ><button  data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" >&nbsp;</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td  width="17%" style="min-width:3em" ><input type="number" class = "entryprice_class" name="entryprice" id="entryprice_2" size="5" min="0" placeholder="0" value="0"></td>
            <td style="min-width:2em"><input type="range" name="slider-fill" class= "entry_percent" id="entry_percent_2" value="50" placeholder="50%" min="0" max="100"
                                             data-highlight="true"/></td>
            <td width="17%" style="min-width:3em"><input type="text" class="order_amount" name="order_amount" size="5" min="0" placeholder="0" length="10px" disabled></td>
            <td width="17%" style="min-width:3em"><input type="text" class ="capital_value" name="capital_value" size="5" min="0" placeholder="0"  disabled></td>
            <td width="17%" style="min-width:3em"><input type="text" class ="breakeven" name="breakeven" size="5" min="0" placeholder="0" disabled></td>
            <td width="28px"><a href="#" class="remove_field">
              <button  data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true">&nbsp;</button>
              </a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <table class="responsive" id="totals_table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Totals: </th>
            <th scope="col">Total order amount</th>
            <th scope="col">Cummulative breakeven</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td  width="17%" style="min-width:3em" ><input type="number" class = "entryprice_totals" name="entryprice_totals" id="entryprice_totals_1" size="5" min="0" placeholder="0" value="0"></td>
            <td style="display:none;min-width:2em" ><input type="range" name="slider-fill" value="50" placeholder="50%" min="0" max="100"
                               data-highlight="true"/></td>
            <td width="17%" style="min-width:3em"><input type="text" class="order_amount_totals" name="order_amount_totals_name" id="order_amount_totals_id" size="5" min="0" placeholder="0" length="10px" disabled></td>
            <td width="17%" style="min-width:3em"><input type="text" class ="breakeven_totals_class" name="breakeven_totals" size="5" min="0" placeholder="0" disabled id="break_even_totals_id"></td>
            <td width="28px" style="display:none" ><button  data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" >&nbsp;</button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-grid-solo">
      <div class="ui-block-a">
        <div>
          <button id='add_new_entry_button' data-icon="plus" data-inline="false">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<!-- /content -->

</div>

<!-- /page --> 

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


       // ================= calculate sliders ==================
        var entry_percent_class = $('.entry_percent');
        var previous_value = 50;

        var remaining_percent;
        var change = 0;

        $(".entry_percent").live("slidestop",function(){
            if ($(this).data("oldvalue")!==undefined) {
                previous_value = $(this).data("oldvalue");
            }
            $(this).data("oldvalue",$(this).val());

            //console.log('Slide stop previous value:'+ previous_value);
        });


        $(".entry_percent").live("slidestart",function(){
            if ($(this).data("oldvalue")!==undefined)
                previous_value = $(this).data("oldvalue");
                //console.log("Slide start prev value: "+ previous_value);
        });


        entry_percent_class.live('focus', function() { // if the user inputs a number in the slider box, capture the number before it's changed.
            if ($(this).data("oldvalue")!==undefined) {
                previous_value = $(this).data("oldvalue");
            }
            previous_value = $(this).val();
            //console.log('Focus event'+ previous_value);
        });


        entry_percent_class.live('change', function(e) {
            var current_value = $(this).val();
            var slider_sum = 100 - previous_value;
            var remaining_percent = 100 - current_value;

            console.log('Slider sums (exluding current): ' + slider_sum);
            console.log('Remaing: ' + remaining_percent);


            // iterate through sliders & change them, excluding the current slider

            var sliders = $('.entry_percent').not(this);
            //iterate through each input and add to sum
            $(sliders).each(function() {
                var current_value = parseFloat(this.value);
                console.log('Current slider value: ' + current_value);

                var updated_value = (current_value / slider_sum) * remaining_percent;
                console.log('Updated slider value: ' + updated_value);

               //$(this).slider('value', updated_value);

                //$(this).slider('refresh');

                $(this).val(updated_value).slider('refresh');

            });


        });


    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have scope problems.  `this` doesn't exist at time of `var sliders = $('.entry_percent').not(this);` declaration.  `this` is part of an event.  declaring a var is not an event.  The rest of the `this`calls down stream won't work either because of it.

Comment: I have trouble understanding what is it you want to achieve. Could you make it clearer?

Comment: When a slider value is changed, I want to update the remaining slider values in ratio to each other, all values equaling 100.